# Meaning of the idiom "here falls the shadow"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does the expression "here falls the shadow" mean?

The context is a list describing how to teach your kids to become entrepreneurs:

> 6. **Teach the mental nexus**. Here falls the shadow. Rational people do not become entrepreneurs [...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly in your specific context, "*Here falls the shadow*" is something like "*Here is the problem*".

Culturally, *shadows* easily refers to *darkness*, to something *black* and depending of the context, something *bad*, something that *goes wrong*.

What your sentence is bringing up is that *irrational people are those that become entrepeneurs*. They should be madness, creative; they should think outside of the box to make big deals and ***here is the problem***: people commonly are too rationals to go off the line.

Comment: Is there a source? https://www.google.com/search?q=define+Here+falls+the+shadow doesn't pull up anything.

Answer (score 3):

I believe "Falls the Shadow" is a reference to the uncertainty of an entrepreneurial life and possibly a reference to T.S. Eliot's **The Hollow Men**

[Between the idea
And the reality
Between the motion
And the act
Falls the Shadow](http://www.americanpoems.com/poets/tseliot/1076)

Comment: But do you agree with the contextual use of it?

Comment: In the example, the parent is teaching the child to become an entrepreneur, and therefore the desire suggests that the context is not that the entrepreneurial person is himself irrational but the act or the business of entrepreneurship is a leap of faith - shadowed and unknown- but a goal worth pursuing